# How to install java7 version to Run an applet in web broswer

Tags: java, applet

I am running an applet program in my browser.When i am running that applet the browser is asking to me install java7.And then i am redirecting to [`THIS LINK`](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp).When i download java and install the applet is working fine.**When i install i got only jre only.I did not get jdk.**

My Question is:

I heard one thing previously.Browser contains java.So if it is correct ,Why i need to install java7 in my system.Only browser need java7 version.Is there any possibility to install in browser only.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Browsers don't contain Java, they have a JavaScript engine/implementation which is not the same thing.  You require Java because it contains the runtime environment and plugin to execute Java code (like applets).  Is the same reason you need to download Flash.  Update- The JDK needs to be download separately and isn't required in day-to-day interactions with Java unless you are developing with it

Comment: But the redirected link is java7 version related one.

Comment: And?  The latest updates to Java 7 included fixes to a potential security risk in the plugin

Comment: @MadProgrammer when i install java7 in my system will browser automatically take that jre

Comment: Depends on the browser

Comment: Why do you need the JDK?

Comment: @MadProgrammer But in some other system in firefox it is not working.But in my system in all browsers it is working.How i can resolve this issue?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Just i am saying what is happening here

Comment: It's likely that they don't have Java installed or the right version of Java, you will require them to download it and install it

Comment: But in other browsers working like chrome.

Comment: @seedi sure, but if you do not need the JDK specifically the JRE is fine.

Answer (score 1):

JRE  includes browser plugins for Applet execution. You only need java runtime to run your applet. JDK is development kit(which BTW includes JRE) but you don't need it in your case.

For Applet's Execution Environment read corresponding [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/appletExecutionEnv.html).

It says

An applet will run in an existing JRE if the following conditions are met:

1. The JRE version required by the applet matches an existing JRE.
2. The JRE's startup parameters satisfy the applet's requirements.

So all you need is correct JRE version to run your applet.

Comment: Are there any java related plugins available to install in browser?

Comment: @seedi as I stated in my answer plugin is a part of JRE. All you have to do is install the correct JRE(version) and enable Java on your browser.

Comment: @seedi Also How do I enable Java in my web browser? http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not correct.  They require a JRE installed on the OS and a plug-in in the browser to glue them together.

Many years ago (Windows 95?) Windows included a JRE by default, so there was no need to install Java.  Perhaps from here the confusion, but these times are long gone.

Comment: Are there any java related plugins available to install in browser?

Comment: AFAIK, plugins for the most common browsers are installed with the JRE .

Answer (score 0):

**Java Runtime Environment**

Java Runtime Environment contains JVM, class libraries, and other supporting files.

> It does not contain any development tools such as compiler, debugger,
> etc. Actually JVM runs the program, and it uses the class libraries,
> and other supporting files provided in JRE. If you want to run any
> java program, you need to have JRE installed in the system

The Java Virtual Machine provides a platform-independent way of executing code; programmers can concentrate on writing software, without having to be concerned with how or where it will run.

> If u just want to run applets (ex: Online Yahoo games or puzzles), JRE
> needs to be installed on the machine. JVM (Java Virtual Machine)

**JDK (Java Development Kit)**

Java Developer Kit contains tools needed to develop the Java programs, and JRE to run the programs. The tools include compiler (javac.exe), Java application launcher (java.exe), Appletviewer, etc…

Compiler converts java code into byte code. Java application launcher opens a JRE, loads the class, and invokes its main method.

> You need JDK, if at all you want to write your own programs, and to
> compile the m. For running java programs, JRE is sufficient.
>
> JRE is targeted for execution of Java files

i.e. JRE = JVM + Java Packages Classes(like util, math, lang, awt,swing etc)+runtime libraries.

JDK is mainly targeted for java development. I.e. You can create a Java file (with the help of Java packages), compile a Java file and run a java file
JRE (Java Runtime Environment)

Comment: so you mean if i want to develop some thing in java we need jdk . But when i want to run a program which is developed in java we need jre.

Comment: @seedi Exactly, Because it contain JVM..!!